# Can different meta data (App info, Screen shots) be uploaded for an iOS app for different territory

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

For an iOS app, can we provide different meta data (App information, screenshots, support URLs etc..) based on territory. 
For my app, screen shots are different , as some features are supported in a country and some are not.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it based on territory but you can do it based on language and I think that should work for you. Check the link below to see how to upload app for multiple languages with localization.
https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206217368-How-to-add-localized-app-descriptions-in-iTunes-Connect

Comment: @Kushal Dugar: Can different screenshots also be provided along with with meta data.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different screen as per localisation, for this on `appstoreconnect` portal select prepare for submission on left panel, `App Previews and Screenshots` section you can add different screen for different localized.

[image]

From localized section select your preferred language, now there is and option `Use English (U.S.) Display` deselect this checkbox to add screenshot of localized language.